# iOS - debugging tool to detect view touched

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, touch

Wondering if anyone has written or come across a good way to log to the console the view that a touch occurred in. I know touchesEnded: can be implemented, but my problem is that something mysterious is blocking touches on my views and I don't know what it is. I would just like to know what is intercepting the touches.

I would like to log to the console:

"Touch occurred in view: nameOfSomeUIView"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each `UITouch` object has a view property described as "The view in which the touch initially occurred." You can subclass `UIWindow` and override the `sendEvent` method. In your implementation of `sendEvent` you can call `[super sendEvent: event]` and after that inspect the view properties of all the touches that belong to the event.

As a general tip:
Check the `hitTest` method of your views if your `UITouches` do not behave as expected. You can override this method to see which view should receive touches.

Comment: I have subclassed UIWindow and used the subclass type in the App Delegate. I implemented - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event in the subclass, but it is never getting called.

Comment: Actually scratch that, I'm getting sendEvent now. Can you suggest how to find which view is being touched?

Comment: Figured out how to pull the touch out of the UIEvent. I can get the memory address of the view being touched. Would be nice if I could get it's name.

Comment: You could use the "tag" property of your views to identify them. 

Otherwise add a name property to your subclass "MyView" of "UIView" and if on of the "touch.view" objects is an instance of "MyView" log it's name property. Hope this helps.

Comment: Without subclassing you can also sometimes guess which UIView was clicked based on its frame origin and size that can be printed out in the console...

Comment: @sol I know this question is old (this is also for others)... This may help to determine the name of the class from the memory address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462768/get-class-from-instance-hex-in-objective-c