# App crashes in iOS10 after Xcode 8 upgrade, malloc error returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have recently upgraded to iOS10 and Xcode 8, following this some previously working code is now no longer working. When the code runs the app crashes and the following error message is displayed in the console:

malloc: *** error for object 0x1700bea80: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I have done some testing and have narrowed the error to the function 'createNativeAd' in the following code.

Can anyone see why this error might be thrown?

```
//
//  FacebookAdPlugin.m
//  TestAdMobCombo
//
//  Created by Xie Liming on 14-11-8.
//
//

#import <FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.h>
#import "UITapGestureRecognizer+Spec.h"
#import "FacebookAdPlugin.h"

#define TEST_BANNER_ID           @"726719434140206_777151452430337"
#define TEST_INERSTITIAL_ID      @"726719434140206_777151589096990"
#define TEST_NATIVE_ID           @"726719434140206_777151705763645"

#define OPT_DEVICE_HASH          @"deviceHash"

@interface FacebookAdPlugin()<FBAdViewDelegate, FBInterstitialAdDelegate, FBNativeAdDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (assign) FBAdSize adSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* nativeads;

- (void) __removeNativeAd:(NSString*)adId;
- (void) fireNativeAdLoadEvent:(FBNativeAd*)nativeAd;

@end


// ------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface UITrackingView : UIView

@end

@implementation UITrackingView
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Always ignore the touch event, so that we can scroll the webview beneath.
    // We will inovke GestureRecognizer callback ourselves.
    return nil;
}
@end

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface FlexNativeAd : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* adId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FBNativeAd* ad;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITrackingView* view;
@property (assign) int x,y,w,h;

- (FlexNativeAd*) init;

@end

@implementation FlexNativeAd

- (FlexNativeAd*) init
{
    self.adId = NULL;
    self.ad = NULL;
    self.view = NULL;
    self.x = 0;
    self.y = 0;
    self.w = 0;
    self.h = 0;

    return self;
}

@end

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

@implementation FacebookAdPlugin

- (void)pluginInitialize
{
    [super pluginInitialize];

    self.adSize = [self __AdSizeFromString:@"SMART_BANNER"];
    self.nativeads = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (NSString*) __getProductShortName{
    return @"FacebookAds";
}

- (NSString*) __getTestBannerId;
{
    return TEST_BANNER_ID;
}

- (NSString*) __getTestInterstitialId
{
    return TEST_INERSTITIAL_ID;
}

- (FBAdSize) __AdSizeFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    FBAdSize sz;
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"BANNER"]) {
        sz = kFBAdSize320x50;
    // other size not supported by facebook audience network: FULL_BANNER, MEDIUM_RECTANGLE, LEADERBOARD, SKYSCRAPER
    //} else if ([str isEqualToString:@"SMART_BANNER"]) {
    } else {
        BOOL isIPAD = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
        sz = isIPAD ? kFBAdSizeHeight90Banner : kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner;
    }

    return sz;
}

- (void) parseOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    [super parseOptions:options];

    NSString* str = [options objectForKey:OPT_AD_SIZE];
    if(str) {
        self.adSize = [self __AdSizeFromString:str];
    }

    if(self.isTesting) {
        self.testTraffic = true;

        str = [options objectForKey:OPT_DEVICE_HASH];
        if(str && [str length]>0) {
            NSLog(@"set device hash: %@", str);
            [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:str];
        }

        // TODO: add device hash, but know how to get the FB hash id on ios ...
    }
}


- (UIView*) __createAdView:(NSString*)adId
{
    FBAdView* ad = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:adId
                                                  adSize:self.adSize
                                      rootViewController:[self getViewController]];
    ad.delegate= self;

    if(self.adSize.size.height == 50 || self.adSize.size.height == 90) {
        ad.autoresizingMask =
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    }

    return ad;
}

- (int) __getAdViewWidth:(UIView*)view
{
    return view.frame.size.width;
}

- (int) __getAdViewHeight:(UIView*)view
{
    return view.frame.size.height;
}

- (void) __loadAdView:(UIView*)view
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[FBAdView class]]) {
        FBAdView* ad = (FBAdView*) view;
        [ad loadAd];
    }
}

- (void) __pauseAdView:(UIView*)view
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[FBAdView class]]) {
        //FBAdView* ad = (FBAdView*) view;
        // [ad pause];
    }
}

- (void) __resumeAdView:(UIView*)view
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[FBAdView class]]) {
        //FBAdView* ad = (FBAdView*) view;
        // [ad resume];
    }
}

- (void) __destroyAdView:(UIView*)view
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[FBAdView class]]) {
        FBAdView* ad = (FBAdView*) view;
        ad.delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (NSObject*) __createInterstitial:(NSString*)adId
{
    FBInterstitialAd* ad = [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:adId];
    ad.delegate = self;

    return ad;
}

- (void) __loadInterstitial:(NSObject*)interstitial
{
    if([interstitial isKindOfClass:[FBInterstitialAd class]]) {
        FBInterstitialAd* ad = (FBInterstitialAd*) interstitial;
        [ad loadAd];
    }
}

- (void) __showInterstitial:(NSObject*)interstitial
{
    if([interstitial isKindOfClass:[FBInterstitialAd class]]) {
        FBInterstitialAd* ad = (FBInterstitialAd*) interstitial;
        if(ad && ad.isAdValid) {
            [ad showAdFromRootViewController:[self getViewController]];
        }
    }
}

- (void) __destroyInterstitial:(NSObject*)interstitial
{
    if([interstitial isKindOfClass:[FBInterstitialAd class]]) {
        FBInterstitialAd* ad = (FBInterstitialAd*) interstitial;
        ad.delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (void)handleTapOnWebView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"handleTapOnWeb");

    for(id key in self.nativeads) {
        FlexNativeAd* unit = (FlexNativeAd*) [self.nativeads objectForKey:key];
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:unit.view];
        if([unit.view pointInside:point withEvent:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Native Ad view area tapped");

            NSArray* handlers = [unit.view gestureRecognizers];
            for(id handler in handlers) {
                if([handler isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapHandler = (UITapGestureRecognizer*) handler;

                    // Here we call the injected method, defined in "UITapGestureRecognizer+Spec.m"
                    if([tapHandler respondsToSelector:@selector(performTapWithView:andPoint:)]) {
                        [tapHandler performTapWithView:unit.view andPoint:point];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

- (void)createNativeAd:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"createNativeAd");

    if([command.arguments count] >= 1) {
        NSString* adId = [command argumentAtIndex:0];

        if(self.testTraffic) adId = TEST_INERSTITIAL_ID;

        FlexNativeAd* unit = [self.nativeads objectForKey:adId];
        if(unit) {
            if(unit.adId) {
                [self __removeNativeAd:unit.adId];
            }
        }

        unit = [[FlexNativeAd alloc] init];
        unit.adId = adId;

        CGRect adRect = {{0,0},{0,0}};
        unit.view = [[UITrackingView alloc] initWithFrame:adRect];
        [[self getView] addSubview:unit.view];

        // add tap handler to handle tap on webview
        UITapGestureRecognizer *webViewTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnWebView:)];
        webViewTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        webViewTapped.delegate = self;
        [[self getView] addGestureRecognizer:webViewTapped];

        if(self.isTesting) {
            [unit.view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2f]];
        }

        unit.ad = [[FBNativeAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:adId];
        unit.ad.delegate = self;

        [self.nativeads setObject:unit forKey:adId];

        [unit.ad loadAd];

        [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] to:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"invalid arguments"] to:command.callbackId];
    }
}

- (void) __removeNativeAd:(NSString*)adId
{
    FlexNativeAd* unit = [self.nativeads objectForKey:adId];
    if(unit) {
        [self.nativeads removeObjectForKey:adId];

        if(unit.view) {
            CGRect adFrame = {{0,0},{0,0}};
            unit.view.frame = adFrame;
            [unit.view removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if(unit.ad) {
            [unit.ad unregisterView];
        }
    }
}

- (void)removeNativeAd:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"removeNativeAd");

    if([command.arguments count] >= 1) {
        NSString* adId = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
        [self __removeNativeAd:adId];

        [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] to:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"invalid arguments"] to:command.callbackId];
    }
}

- (void)setNativeAdClickArea:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"setNativeAdClickArea");

    if([command.arguments count] >= 5) {
        NSString* adId = [command argumentAtIndex:0];

        FlexNativeAd* unit = [self.nativeads objectForKey:adId];
        if(unit && unit.view) {
            int x = [[command argumentAtIndex:1 withDefault:@"0"] intValue];
            int y = [[command argumentAtIndex:2 withDefault:@"0"] intValue];
            int w = [[command argumentAtIndex:3 withDefault:@"0"] intValue];
            int h = [[command argumentAtIndex:4 withDefault:@"0"] intValue];

            CGRect adRect = {{x,y},{w,h}};
            unit.view.frame = adRect;

            [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] to:command.callbackId];

        } else {
            [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"native ad not exists"] to:command.callbackId];
        }

    } else {
        [self sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"invalid arguments"] to:command.callbackId];
    }
}

#pragma mark FBAdViewDelegate implementation

/**
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLoaded', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdFailLoad', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdPresent', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdDismiss', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLeaveApp', function(data));
 */
- (void)adViewDidClick:(FBAdView *)adView
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_LEAVEAPP withType:ADTYPE_BANNER];
}

- (void)adViewDidFinishHandlingClick:(FBAdView *)adView
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_DISMISS withType:ADTYPE_BANNER];
}

- (void)adViewDidLoad:(FBAdView *)adView
{
    if((! self.bannerVisible) && self.autoShowBanner) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self __showBanner:self.adPosition atX:self.posX atY:self.posY];
        });
    }

    [self fireEvent:[self __getProductShortName] event:@"onBannerReceive" withData:NULL];

    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_LOADED withType:ADTYPE_BANNER];
}

- (void)adView:(FBAdView *)adView didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self fireAdErrorEvent:EVENT_AD_FAILLOAD withCode:(int)error.code withMsg:[error localizedDescription] withType:ADTYPE_BANNER];
}

- (void)adViewWillLogImpression:(FBAdView *)adView
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_PRESENT withType:ADTYPE_BANNER];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - FBInterstitialAdDelegate

/**
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLoaded', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdFailLoad', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdPresent', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdDismiss', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLeaveApp', function(data));
 */
- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    if (self.interstitial && self.autoShowInterstitial) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self __showInterstitial:self.interstitial];
        });
    }

    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_LOADED withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];
}

- (void)interstitialAd:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self fireAdErrorEvent:EVENT_AD_FAILLOAD withCode:(int)error.code withMsg:[error localizedDescription] withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidClick:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_LEAVEAPP withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidClose:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_DISMISS withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];

    if(self.interstitial) {
        [self __destroyInterstitial:self.interstitial];
        self.interstitial = nil;
    }
}

- (void)interstitialAdWillClose:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_WILLDISMISS withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];
}

- (void)interstitialAdWillLogImpression:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_WILLPRESENT withType:ADTYPE_INTERSTITIAL];
}

/**
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLoaded', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdFailLoad', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdPresent', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdDismiss', function(data));
 * document.addEventListener('onAdLeaveApp', function(data));
 */
- (void)nativeAd:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self fireAdErrorEvent:EVENT_AD_FAILLOAD withCode:(int)error.code withMsg:[error localizedDescription] withType:ADTYPE_NATIVE];
}

- (void)nativeAdDidClick:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_LEAVEAPP withType:ADTYPE_NATIVE];
}

- (void)nativeAdDidFinishHandlingClick:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_DISMISS withType:ADTYPE_NATIVE];
}

- (void)nativeAdDidLoad:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    [self fireNativeAdLoadEvent:nativeAd];
}

- (void) fireNativeAdLoadEvent:(FBNativeAd*)nativeAd
{
    [self.nativeads enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString* adId = (NSString*) key;
        FlexNativeAd* unit = (FlexNativeAd*) obj;
        if(unit && unit.ad == nativeAd) {
            NSString *titleForAd = nativeAd.title;
            NSString *bodyTextForAd = nativeAd.body;
            FBAdImage *coverImage = nativeAd.coverImage;
            FBAdImage *iconForAd = nativeAd.icon;
            NSString *socialContextForAd = nativeAd.socialContext;
            struct FBAdStarRating appRatingForAd = nativeAd.starRating;
            NSString *titleForAdButton = nativeAd.callToAction;

            NSMutableDictionary* coverInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [coverInfo setValue:[coverImage.url absoluteString] forKey:@"url"];
            [coverInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:coverImage.width] forKey:@"width"];
            [coverInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:coverImage.height] forKey:@"height"];

            NSMutableDictionary* iconInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [iconInfo setValue:[iconForAd.url absoluteString] forKey:@"url"];
            [iconInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iconForAd.width] forKey:@"width"];
            [iconInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iconForAd.height] forKey:@"height"];

            NSMutableDictionary* adRes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [adRes setValue:coverInfo forKey:@"coverImage"];
            [adRes setValue:iconInfo forKey:@"icon"];
            [adRes setValue:titleForAd forKey:@"title"];
            [adRes setValue:bodyTextForAd forKey:@"body"];
            [adRes setValue:socialContextForAd forKey:@"socialContext"];
            [adRes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:appRatingForAd.value] forKey:@"rating"];
            [adRes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:appRatingForAd.scale] forKey:@"ratingScale"];
            [adRes setValue:titleForAdButton forKey:@"buttonText"];

            NSMutableDictionary* json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [json setValue:[self __getProductShortName] forKey:@"adNetwork"];
            [json setValue:EVENT_AD_LOADED forKey:@"adEvent"];
            [json setValue:ADTYPE_NATIVE forKey:@"adType"];
            [json setValue:adId forKey:@"adId"];
            [json setValue:adRes forKey:@"adRes"];

            NSError * err;
            NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:0 error:&err];
            NSString * jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [unit.ad registerViewForInteraction:unit.view withViewController:[self getViewController]];

            [self fireEvent:[self __getProductShortName] event:EVENT_AD_LOADED withData:jsonStr];

            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}

- (void)nativeAdWillLogImpression:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    [self fireAdEvent:EVENT_AD_PRESENT withType:ADTYPE_NATIVE];
}

@end
```

The full sources code can be found at https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-facebookads

Comment: what `BOOL *stop` is ?

Comment: I'm not sure, does it look suspect?

Comment: just try remove * pointer sign like `BOOL stop` and `stop = YES;` may cause of prob ..

Comment: No it's not that. It is some problem with the 'createNativeAd' function

Comment: set multiple breakpoints inside `createNativeAd` function and check. Do you know how to set breakpoints ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124526/discussion-between-ant-and-vaibhav).

Comment: Today, I try to implement the Native ad of Facebook on Xcode8. I met the same issue. Even, I use the "NativeAdSample" example project from Official Facebook iOS SDK. And I get the same issue. 

"NativeAdSample(10831,0x1b6871c40) malloc: *** error for object 0x1740b1100: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068196/935070

The automatic web inspector of the Mac's Safari is crashing the banner

just disable the automatic web inspection

Safari>Develop>Device>Automatically show web inspector for JSContext

Comment: btw: it should be Safari of Mac. not Safari of iPhone.

Comment: yes, it happens on macOS and Xcode8. there's no this problem <macOS

Answer (score 0):

Set Symbolic Break Point

[image: create symbolic breakpoint]

[image: symbolic break point for malloc_error_break]

and that should tell you your problem in releasing objects.

Comment: I just get a load of hex addresses that I can't interpret

Comment: Try: po [(id)(<address like 0x1700BEA80 >) class] to print the class in your debugger

Comment: That gives: (lldb) po [(id)(0x1924d0b98) class]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xde7ffdf18).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: See the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462768/get-class-from-instance-hex-in-objective-c - may be this works for you.