# Malloc pointer being freed was not allocated -- Ionic1 + cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, wkwebview

Everything was running fine then suddenly this, oh yeah upgraded to Sierra before this bug and now using xCode 8.0.

Malloc: *** error for object 0x1740b6e00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details please ? Does it happens every time ? On which device have you tested (iOS version, emulator or device) ?

Comment: I'm getting this as well, but from a Swift app running on iOS.  It happens after I execute any Javascript from the swift code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43885754/6521116

Answer (score 33):

I struggled with this crash for hours before i finally figured out that Safari was responsible. It was due to the option Develop>Device>Automatically show web inspector for JSContext. If it doesn't work try quit Safari completely.

Comment: Spent hours wasting time on this. Thank you so much

Comment: Great answer!. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One pic is enough, for more refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885754/6521116),

Disable auto safari or safari preview inspect, below is safari preview.

[image]